# Prove that $A$ is Symmetric matrix or antisymmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

let matrix $ A\in R^{n\times n},\alpha\in R^{1\times n}$

if $\forall \alpha, \exists k\in Z $,then we have $A\alpha =kA^T\alpha ,$

prove that 
$A$ is Symmetric matrix or antisymmetric matrix

Comment: What do we know about $k$? Does it depend on $\alpha$ or only on $A$?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: In the first line you write $\alpha \in \mathbb R^{1 \times n}$, in the second $\alpha \in Z$. What is $Z$? If $\alpha \in \mathbb R^{1 \times n}$, $A\alpha$ isn't defined.

Comment: I have tried,But I failured,
..

Comment: Source?${}{}{}$

Comment: Well, $k$ certainly depends on $A$ because not every matrix has this property. But if it does not depend on $\alpha$, it should come before $\forall \alpha$. So  please edit your question.

Comment: oh,Thank you, wait sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=(a_{i,j}$) and let $$e_i=\left(\begin{array}\\0\\
\vdots\\0\\1\\0\\ \vdots\\0\end{array}\right)$$
where the $1$ is placed at the $i^{th}$ position then we have
$$a_{i,j}=e_i^T A e_j=ke_i^T A^Te_j=ka_{i,j}^T=ka_{j,i}$$
hence we can see easily that
$$a_{i,j}=k a_{j,i}=k^2 a_{i,j}$$
so $k^2=1$ and then $k=\pm 1$ and we conclude that $A$ is symmetric or antisymmetric.

Comment: Thank you,if $A\in C^{n\times n},\alpha\in C^{1\times n}$

Comment: @math110 As martini's comment if $\alpha\in \mathbb C^{1\times n}$ then the product $A\alpha$ isn't defined so I think you have a typo and we must take $\alpha \in \mathbb C^{n\times 1}$.

Comment: @julien Even if $k$ depends on $\alpha$ and we find as you said $a_{ij}=k_i k_j a_{ij}$ so $k_i=\pm 1$ moreover $k_i$ and $k_j$ have the same sign so $k_i=1\forall i$ or $k_i=-1\forall i$ and we are done.

Comment: OH,Thank you,@Sami Ben Romdhane .if $k$ depends on $A$,then?

Comment: @math110 If $k$ depends on $A$ or on $\alpha$ we prove as my last comment that $k$ is indeed a constant and its value is $\pm 1$.

Comment: oh,Thank you.It's nice! +1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9244/discussion-between-math110-and-sami-ben-romdhane)

Comment: Now,I consider sometime,But Now I have question,if $k$ depents $\alpha$,if $a_{i,j}=0$? then?